# Strategy - Gridview to Excel export full records

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I know there are a bunch of questions with detailed instructions on exporting from gridview to excel, but I can't find my particular situation.

I have a gridview that displays records with five fields from a search.  Users can check in a checkbox any number of records.  On a button click, I can successfully export only the checked records to Excel.  Export is as HTML.  I'm using the technique from Matt Berseth here: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

I added a check for whether the record was checked by the user and this works fine.

But I have a requirement that for the checked records that are exported, the users want to see the entire records (i.e. all fields in just the selected records).

What is a good strategy to accomplish this?

I've tried retrieving all fields in the gridview and setting all but the five desired fields to not visible.  Then in the export button click event, setting the fields to visible and rebinding.  No luck there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your exported data look like now are you building the HTML from a Comma Delim list..? please be more specific.. if you can get only the checked record..then you should be able to successfully get the full row of the selected record.. show the code that you currently are using to get the checked record..

Comment: I'm using the technique from Matt Berseth here:
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should loop through the rows to see which are checked.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows) 
{
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      CheckBox cb = row.FindControl("CheckBoxID") as CheckBox;

      if(cb != null && cb.Checked) 
      {
        // Logic here.
      }
}
```

From there, you can export to excel using several different mechanisms, depends on your needs. One I've used in the past if you just need xls files is NPOI -- it's open source and provides a decent framework for it.  Here is a link to their site:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

-- EDIT

After reading your comments, maybe this will help.

ASPX Code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Checkbox Column">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxID" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visible Column">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblVisibleColumn"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VisibleColumn")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hidden Column" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHiddenColumn"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HiddenColumn")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
```

Backend Code:

```
        public class MyDataColumn
        {
            public string visibleColumn { get; set; }
            public string hiddenColumn { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                List<MyDataColumn> dataColumns = new List<MyDataColumn>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    dataColumns.Add(new MyDataColumn()
                    {
                        visibleColumn = string.Format("Visible Column {0}", i),
                        hiddenColumn = string.Format("Hidden Column {0}", i)
                    });
                }

                gridView.DataSource = dataColumns;
                gridView.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyDataColumn> dataColumnsToExport = new List<MyDataColumn>();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows) 
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = row.FindControl("CheckBoxID") as CheckBox;

                    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                    {
                        Label lblVisibleColumn = row.FindControl("lblVisibleColumn") as Label;
                        Label lblHiddenColumn = row.FindControl("lblHiddenColumn") as Label;

                        dataColumnsToExport.Add(new MyDataColumn()
                        {
                            visibleColumn = lblVisibleColumn.Text,
                            hiddenColumn = lblHiddenColumn.Text
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            GridView gridViewToExport = new GridView();
            gridViewToExport.DataSource = dataColumnsToExport;
            gridViewToExport.DataBind();

            //Do Something With gridViewToExport
            //GridViewExportUtil.Export("GridView.xls", gridViewToExport);
        }
```

And this should be easy to convert to a DataTable if needed -- I used my own class to make it shorter code.

Comment: Thanks, but that's pretty much what I'm using to test for and add checked records to the data table.  I'm having trouble determining how to get the rest of the fields in the records.  i.e. going from 5 fields to the full 22 fields in the record.  The users want to see everything when they export it.

Comment: use the same type of logic if cb.Checked then add the rest of what you need to do in that foreach logic then break at the end of the 21 other fields

Comment: Would I need to make another query on the database to get the rest of the fields?  For each record?  Or if I query for all fields from the beginning (ex: select * from...), are all of those values available, whether they are set to display or not?  Say, I query for everything, but only display 5 fields, are the other 17 field values available without re-querying?  That's where I'm having trouble.  The other values don't seem to be there, but perhaps I'm trying to access them incorrectly.